# How do I differentiate between placeholders (Tags, Id, Name) on a template and have the label stay once the template is used in the presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am creating a custom slide template with 8 picture placeholders and 4 text placeholders. The idea is that the user would "fill-in" the template with the text and images and once a macro is run, the values of the placeholders would be collected and added to a JSON file. Ideally, two picture placeholders (big_screen_i and small_screen_i) and one text placeholder (caption_i) would be collected as one JSON object. This set would be repeated 4 times on the same slide.

Here are my problems: 
1) The name of the placeholder set in the slide master view changes when more than one of the same template is used (haven't pinpointed the exact trigger). The names also change once an image is inserted into the placeholder. Locating an object by name becomes unstable. 
2) Using the .type of placeholder (picture vs text) doesn't differentiate between the big_screen_i and small_screen_i.
3) Tags and keys also change or disappear when using the template more than once (because of the repeated name).
4) I am unable to group the objects because its not possible to group placeholders.

Is there a way to identify each shape/placeholder and connect it to the added content?

Note: I am using powerpoint 2016 .potm file

Thank You!

Comment: What precisely do you mean when you use the term "template"?  It has a specific meaning in PPTSpeak (POT/POTX files) but that doesn't seem to mate up with your use of the term.  IAC, the z-order of the placeholder shapes on the slide will match the z-order of the placeholders on the layout, so you might be able to match things up that way.

Comment: Hi there! By template I mean creating a new layout on Slide Master. If I were to go with the z-order, is that a stable number - meaning if I add multiple of the same layout to my presentation, will I be able to access the same placeholder using the same z-order on each slide with the same layout? How would I access the z-order value of an object? Thanks again!

Comment: A slide can only be based on one layout, regardless of how many layouts are included in the current slide master. The z-order of shapes on the layout is stable; adding other layouts won't have any effect on a given layout.  If you iterate through all the shapes on the layout (ie, for x = 1 to .shapes.count), you'll get the shapes in z-order, but for a given shape, its .ZOrderPosition will give you the z-order